# Haskell giving index for the items in list

Tags: haskell

In a function I should number the elements of a list, which should return like this: "n: rest of the string"

```
numberLines :: [String] -> [String]

["asd  qwe", "-- Foo", "", "\thello world "] 
   -> ["1: asd  qwe", "2: -- Foo", "3: ", "4: \thello world "]
```

I'm not allowed to use simple recursion, only higher order functions (if needed)

My problems:

1. I don't know how to make the counter
2. I don't know how to put an Int in front of the string (`"counter: " ++ "string"` will not work)

Comment: Suggestion: take a look to function `zipWith`

Comment: You don't need a counter, just every index you might ever need: `[1..]`.

Comment: The `Show` instance for your indices should be sufficient: `show 1 == "1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` that will concurrently enumerate through two lists and produce a list of items where *c<sub>i</sub>* is *f a<sub>i</sub> b<sub>i</sub>* for `c = zipWith f a b`. As first item you can for example feed it an infinite list `[1..]` and as second the list of lines, so:

```
numberLines :: [String] -> [String]
numberLines = zipWith f [1..]
    where f idx st = …
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people want you to use `zipWith`. While this will give the right answer, it consumes two lists, and so doesn't fully support list fusion, which can only work on one list at a time. Here's an alternative solution that can fully fuse:

```
numberLines :: [String] -> [String]
numberLines xs = foldr (\st acc idx -> …:acc (idx+1)) mempty xs 1
```

As in Willem Van Onsem's answer, you'll need to fill in the `…` part yourself.